# Count how often a Text is given in an txt File Python

Tags: python, count

how is it possible for me to count the word "OFFLINE" in the Following List with Python? The List is in a .txt File so i need to open that first i guess and then look after the specific word.

`MPP MPP Fault MPP Fault MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE`

The values as under each another.

I already tried this:

```
    def word_count(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split()

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts

print( word_count(open(info).read()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def word_count(str):
    return str.split().count("OFFLINE")
```

If the goal is to count the number of `OFFLINE` occurences, you don't need a dict.

```py
def word_count(str):
    counts = 0
    words = str.split()
    for word in words:
        if word == "OFFLINE":
            counts += 1
    return counts
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following your approach:**

You need to send the word that you are looking for as parameter:

```
text = "MPP MPP Fault MPP Fault MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP MPP OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE OFFLINE"

def word_count(str, your_word):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split()

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts[your_word]

print(word_count(text, 'OFFLINE'))
```

**Second solution:**

```
print(text.count('OFFLINE'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count()` function for this.
My example .txt file has the following contents:

```
MPP Fault offline offline OFFLINE MPP
```

This is my Script:

```
file = open("test.txt", "r") 
data = file.read()
word = "offline"
occurrences = data.count(word)
print('Number of occurrences of the word :', occurrences)
```

Output:

```
Number of occurrences of the word : 2
```

Note that the `count()` function is case-sensitive. So it did not count "OFFLINE" but only "offline". If I want it to be case-insensitive I can add a transformation to my string beforehand with the upper() function.

```
occurrences = data.upper().count(word.upper())
```

Output:

```
Number of occurrences of the word : 3
```

I retrieved the example from: https://pythonexamples.org/python-count-occurrences-of-word-in-text-file/

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(text.split())
print(c)
print(c['OFFLINE'])
```

Use the built-in `Counter` class to count all words. Counter is inherited from `dict` with some additional methods.

Outputs:

```
Counter({'MPP': 23, 'OFFLINE': 14, 'Fault': 2})
14
```